# Heat generation rate to temperature

Tags: resistors, temperature, heat, mems, power-generation

I have heatgeneration rate in W/m3 and I wanted to know how much temperature it can generate. The heatgeneration element is Platinum resistor for MEMS project. I want to know numerical relation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To find the temperature rise you will need to analyze the [heat loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer) vs. temperature by all methods (typically conduction, radiation and convection).

Conduction can often be approximated as a simple linear relationship for a fixed geometry (like Ohm's law). Radiation loss is very nonlinear (proportional to the difference of the 4th power of the absolute temperatures) and convection is.. complex.. with different types of fluid flow possible under different conditions.

It's possible to use programs such as COMSOL or NASTRAN to analyze the effects, but quite a bit of work will be necessary to model the situation if you want the result to resemble reality.

Comment: I am solving using Ansys, but i wanted to solve it numerically?

Comment: Thank you for the message. I am solving using ansys, I am getting a Temperature rise of 310 degree centigrate. But can you help me how to solve numerically?